# Scale by selection

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have received a PDF-template from a printing company that, among other things, contains an object like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, the measurements printed next to it are nowhere near the actual object dimensions. I already scaled the template manually according to my needs, but I wondered whether there's a clever tool in Illustrator that lets me do this.

I'm thinking of a tool similar to the measurement tool, that let's me measure the height of the orange square, change its height, but then resizes the entire template based on the change I made. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Not without scripting it.

You can always just change the `W` and `H` fields in the control bar size something to a specific size.

So you could select that entire object, orange and black, and then just enter `341mm` in the `H` field.

Comment: Or you can type `311mm + 15mm`+ *tab* + `+15mm`, to avoid caclulating. Though i dont uderstand why you cant type `311mm + 15mm +15mm`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform window and width and height value changer on the upper right corner as shown.

[image: enter w x h values]

[image]